# Videocapture error: Assertion desc failed at src/libswscale/swscale_internal.h:668 error

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

Videocapture read give me this error.  It started recently when I updated to opencv4.  No errors on opencv4 installation.  libswscale is up to date, I have libswscale.so.4.8.100.

The code is a simple "open" and "read" video to isolate the problem:

```
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    cv::VideoCapture video;
    std::string filename(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "filename " << filename << std::endl;
    std::cout << "video.open " << video.open(filename) << std::endl;
    union {
        char ch[5] = {0};
        int i4cc;
    } fourcc;
    fourcc.i4cc = (int) video.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
    std::cout << "Fourcc " << fourcc.ch << std::endl;
    cv::Mat frame;
    while(true){
        std::cout << "video.read " << video.read(frame) << ", Mat.rows " << frame.rows << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("imagen", frame);
    }
}
```

The output is this

```
filename ../Archivos/Vuelta al Lab Uno 720p.MP4
video.open 1
Fourcc avc1
Assertion desc failed at src/libswscale/swscale_internal.h:668
```

VideoCapture opens the video file, shows fourcc property, and then fails to read first image.

If you ask, video file is fine, I tried with other video files and other video formats, with the same error.  These videos play well with ffmpeg.ffplay!

By the way, VideoCapture.read is working fine with webcam.  So, it's not clear where the problem is.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `libswscale.so.4.8.100` corresponds to FFmpeg 3.4.5. You probably need to compile the [latest stable version 4.1](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases) and recompile OpenCV.

Comment: @aergistal, it makes sense, trying right now, I'll let you know. Thank you.